# Spring and returning protected resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a pretty standard Spring 3.0.7 web app

The structure is like this

```
WebContent/
    resources/
      myStaticConent/
    WEB-INF/
       views/
       myProtectedContent/
```

I am using the `<mvc:resources>` configuration for the static content and my controllers get views using the InternalViewResolver from WEB-INF/views

Now I have a requirement to return non-JSP content ( JPGs,PNGs,HTML,etc ) from a protected directory in WEB-INF

So a user might enter a URL like http:myWebApp/myProtectedContent and hit my protected content controller.

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

@RequestMapping(value="/myProtectedContent")
public String index() {
  return "myjpg.jpg";
 }
}
```

Essentially I want to conditionally serve a file just like I would a view. Anyone know how this can be done ?

I looked at some of the other methods here, Streaming using Inputstream seems overkill for files that are essentially static. Can I register another "view" type ? I need this to appear l( from the web browser side ) like a standard http request response ( like the current view implementation).

I would really like to avoid inventing my own file handling methods unless there is some reason why using the file access methods are better then Springs "other" view resolvers like ResourceBundleResolver

So the requirement is 
Conditionally respond to a http request with variable file type (jpg,png,html) from inside WEB-INF without wrapping in a jsp or having the file interpreted by the JSTL view. The names of the files are known and static. The controller will determine the file name based on its own business logic.

Comment: In what way do you want the content served conditionally? Do different users get different resources? Are all resources secure and any logged in person can get at all the resources, but you want a single URL to return different content based on the user? If you could be a bit more clear about the requirements, that might help. Thanks.

Comment: @Kerian I think the use case is a different question and not my information to share. I will clarify what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce the behavior of the underlying implementation of `<mvc:resources/>` which is `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler`, which essentially streams out the content of the static files - You can like ResourceHttpRequestHandler, extend from `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator` which has extensive support for sending last-modified and caching related headers, and finally to stream the content also there is a utility that Spring provides:

```
org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
```

Updated:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController implements ApplicationContextAware  {
    ApplicatonContext ctx = ...;

    @RequestMapping(value="/myProtectedContent")
    public void index(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        Resource resource = ctx.getResource("classpath:staticpath/myjpg.jpg");
        FileCopyUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of effort for what seems like a simple task. Wouldn't be easier to create another internal view resolver ?? Or use another one of the resolvers ?

Comment: No, it is not complicated, what I am essentially saying is that you define the controller the way you have defined, and in the method call FileCopyUtils.copy(resource.getI...), and if you want any of the advanced features like caching, then extend from WebContentGenerator to do that.

Comment: FileCopy ? I dont see how that is better then using InputStream. Also why not use ResourceBundleResolver or UrlResolver ? Can you show an example of what you are suggesting ?

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is to map a new servlet to the path you want to be protected and handle the request the way you want.

For example, in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>protServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/protServlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>protServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myProtectedContent</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way, you map a new servlet (DispatcherServlet) for URLs that are protected content.
The load-on-startup value equals 2 is due if you already have a DispatcherServlet with this field value equals 1.

Comment: Thanks vitor but i need to keep this in the same servlet for portability reasons